# How can I automatically rename, copy and delete files in linux for my ip camera webcam?

Tags: linux, ftp, webcam, ip-camera

I have an ip camera that automatically ftps images every few seconds to directory on my linux Ubuntu Server web server.  I'd like to make a simple webcam page that references a static image and just refreshes every few seconds.  The problem is that my ipcamera's firmware automatically names every file with a date_time.jpg type filename, and does not have the option to overwrite with the same file name over and over.

I'd like to have a script running on my linux machine to automatically copy a new file that has been ftp'd into a directory into a different directory, rename it in the process and then delete the original.

Regards,
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick script, you would need to uncomment the rm -f line to make it delete things :)

it currently prints the command it would have run, so you can test with higher confidence.

You also need to set THE WORK_DIR and DEST_DIR variables near the top of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#########################
# configure vars

YYYYMMDD=`date +%Y%m%d`
WORK_DIR=/Users/neil/linuxfn
DEST_DIR=/Users/neil/linuxfn/dest_dir
##########################

LATEST=`ls -tr $WORK_DIR/$YYYYMMDD* 2>/dev/null | tail -1`
echo "rm -f $DEST_DIR/image.jpg ; mv $LATEST $DEST_DIR/image.jpg"
#rm -f $DEST_DIR/image.jpg ; mv $LATEST $DEST_DIR/image.jpg
```

This give me the following output when i run it on my laptop:

`mba1:linuxfn neil$ bash renamer.sh 
    rm -f /Users/neil/linuxfn/dest_dir/image.jpg ; mv /Users/neil/linuxfn/20150411-2229 /Users/neil/linuxfn/dest_dir/image.jpg`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script example.  I'm going to try to use it as the starting point to get to what I want.  I've had to learn about permissions, shells, etc and haven' quite there yet, but I am making headway thanks to your comments and example.  Can you explain what the * 2>/dev/null means?

Comment: I was able to find out that the * when used within a script will cause the ls command to read all files and subdirectories.  And also found out that the 2>/dec/null means if there is an error, discard the output.

Comment: I have edited what you gave me to start and it is working.  Now I just need to figure out how to start it running in the background, and add a 10 second timer, and loop command.

Comment: you could run it inside a loop like : while (true) ; do things ; sleep 10 ; done

Answer (score 0):

Inotify (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) can be set up to do as you ask, but it would probably be better to use a simple web script (PHP, Python, Perl, etc.) to serve the latest file from the directory, instead.